# Security Exception for ContentProvider.notifyChange on my own URI in Oreo

Tags: java, android, securityexception, android-8.0-oreo

This one has been asked before - but never answered. So I try my luck again.

My app is a perfect clone of Google's IO Schedule app in terms of synchronization - I use exactly their code at [this](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/e4364eec0d8f358215aee30cce2b4836ec169b5a/lib/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/service/DataBootstrapService.java#L93) position.

When running against SDK 25 everything works here - when I go to 26, it crashes with this exception:

```
12-28 21:11:13.641 6153-6190/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[DataBootstrapService]
                                                 Process: de.XXX.XXX.debug, PID: 6153
                                                 java.lang.SecurityException: Failed to find provider null for user 0; expected to find a valid ContentProvider for this authority
```

As suggested in other resources: YES, I have set an authority on my content provider.
This error is ridiculous. I have no idea why it comes up with null and user 0.

Does anyone have an idea of what to look for?
Thanks!

You asked for more details, but I do EXACTLY as Google does in IO Schedule.

My AndroidManifest includes my Provider as follows:

```
<provider
        android:name=".provider.PendelbusProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:syncable="true"/>
```

The line that causes the crash is this:

```
getContentResolver().notifyChange(Uri.parse(PendelbusContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY), null, false);
```

My CONTENT_AUTHORITY is defined like this: (indirectly through build variables)

```
public static final String CONTENT_AUTHORITY = BuildConfig.AUTHORITY;
 // equals to: "de.zordid.pendelbus.debug.provider"
```

I do not understand at all what the message is supposed to indicate.

What is "provider null" and what is "user 0"?

Comment: please post the content uri of your provider, the authority and how you access it from your other app or class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my problem lies in the definition of an URI and the authority derived from that using `Uri.getAuthority()`.

Pair this with a classic BUG in Google's own software, the Google IO Schedule app which is open source.

In their `DataBootstrapService` line 93, they do this:

`getContentResolver().notifyChange(Uri.parse(ScheduleContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY), null, false);`

But, what I did not know: ScheduleContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY is a string containing only the authority. It does NOT make a valid URI, so this is buggy from the very beginning and lead into my problems.

If you test this created Uri and call `getAuthority`, you will see the damn `null`.

Fix: use something like `BASE_CONTENT_URI` which is only "content://"+ AUTHORITY. Then it's fixed.

Hope this helps others.